# Tokenize and label HTML source code using Python

Tags: python, html, token

I have some annotated HTML source code, where the code is similar to what you would get using `requests` and the annotations are labels with the character index where the labelled item starts and

For example, the source code could be:

```
<body><text>Hello world!</text><text>This is my code. And this is a number 42</text></body>
```

and the labels could be for example:

```
[{'label':'salutation', 'start':12, 'end':25},
 {'label':'verb', 'start':42, 'end':45},
 {'label':'size', 'start':75, 'end':78}]
```

Referring to the words 'Hello world', 'is' and '42' respectively. We know in advance that the labels are not overlapping.

I want to process the source code and the annotations to produce a list of tokens appropriate for the HTML format.

For example, it could produce here something like this:

```
['<body>', '<text>', 'hello', 'world', '</text>', '<text>', 'this', 'is', 'my', 'code', 'and', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'number', '[NUMBER]', '</text>', '</body>']
```

Furthermore, it must map the annotations to the tokenization, producing a sequence of labels of the same length as the tokenization such as:

```
['NONE', 'NONE', 'salutation', 'salutation', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'verb', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'size', 'NONE', 'NONE']
```

What is the easiest way of accomplishing this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with `BeautifulSoup` to produce a list of all tags and content, which can then be used to match the labels:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
content = '<body><text>Hello world!</text><text>This is my code. And this is a number 42</text></body>'
def tokenize(d):
  yield f'<{d.name}>'
  for i in d.contents:
     if not isinstance(i, str):
       yield from tokenize(i)
     else:
       yield from i.split()
  yield f'</{d.name}>'

data = list(tokenize(soup(content, 'html.parser').body))
```

Output:

```
['<body>', '<text>', 'Hello', 'world!', '</text>', '<text>', 'This', 'is', 'my', 'code.', 'And', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'number', '42', '</text>', '</body>']
```

Then, to match the labels:

```
labels = [{'label':'salutation', 'start':12, 'end':25}, {'label':'verb', 'start':42, 'end':45}, {'label':'size', 'start':75, 'end':78}] 
tokens = [{**i, 'word':content[i['start']:i['end']-1].split()} for i in labels]
indices = {i:iter([[c, c+len(i)+1] for c in range(len(content)) if re.findall('^\W'+i, content[c-1:])]) for i in data}  
new_data = [[i, next(indices[i], None)] for i in data]
result = [(lambda x:'NONE' if not x else x[0])([c['label'] for c in tokens if b and c['start'] <= b[0] and b[-1] <= c['end']]) for a, b in new_data]
```

Output:

```
['NONE', 'NONE', 'salutation', 'salutation', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'verb', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'NONE', 'size', 'NONE', 'NONE']
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I have made this work using HTMLParser:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

class HTML_tokenizer_labeller(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self, annotations, *args, **kwargs):
    super(HTML_tokenizer_labeller, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.tokens = []
    self.labels = []
    self.annotations = annotations

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    self.tokens.append(f'<{tag}>')
    self.labels.append('OTHER')

  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
    self.tokens.append(f'</{tag}>')
    self.labels.append('OTHER')

  def handle_data(self, data):
    print(f"getpos = {self.getpos()}")
    tokens = text_to_word_sequence(data)

    pos = self.getpos()[1]
    for annotation in annotations:
      if annotation['start'] <= pos <= annotation['end']:
        label = annotation['tag']
        break
    else: label = 'OTHER'

    self.tokens += tokens
    self.labels += [label] * len(tokens)
```